# Easiest way to create a string from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object, lodash

**Note:** ES6 Is welcome, as is loash solutions.

So I have an array, that will only every have two objects of `key: value`

For example:

```
[{a: 1}, {b: 2}]
```

I cannot figure out a solution where it can become: `a_1_b_2` as a string.

You cannot assume the key or the value, so you cannot do something like:

```
let obj = _.merge({}, ...arr);
return `a_${obj.a}_b_${obj.b}`;
```

Because the key's can be any string and the value can be any number. The object's in the array will only ever have one key and one value and there will only ever be two objects in the array.

With this in mind, how do I create the desired string?

Comment: `arr.map(o => Object.keys(o).map(k => k+'_'+o[k])[0]).join('_')` (or any similar variation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution in lodash that uses a combination of [`lodash#flatMapDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flatMapDeep) and [`lodash#toPairs`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#toPairs) to get an array of keys and values that we can join using [`lodash#join`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#join).

```js
var array = [{a: 1}, {b: 2}];

var result = _(array).flatMapDeep(_.toPairs).join('_');
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Map the array using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
- Flatten to a single array using [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) (2 is the number of levels to flattern, use Infinity for unknown number of levels)
- Join the items to a string

```js
const data = [{a: 1}, {b: 2}];

const result = data.map(Object.entries).flat(2).join('_');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I somehow thought `Object.entries` returns an iterator... apparently not.

Comment: Map#entries returns an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

I'd solve this problem doing:

```
obj.map(x => Object.keys(x) + '_' + Object.values(x)).join('_');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let obj = _.merge({}, ...arr);

obj.map(o => {
   var key = Object.keys(o)[0];
   return `${key}_${o[key]}`;
})
.reduce((a, b) => `${a}_${b}`);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

As the others statet you can use map and Object.keys for this job.

Working example: http://jsbin.com/rofufibemu/edit?console

```
const arr = [{a: "foo"}, {b: 1}, {c: "bar"}];
const str = arr.map(item => {
  return Object.keys(item).map(prop => {
    return prop + "_" + item[prop];
  }).join("__");
}).join("___");

console.log(str);
```

The code can be reduced by using template strings, never thought of having such problems typing code on a mobile keyboard ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Everyone else is making this overly complicated and obfuscated IMO. Since you can specify exactly the schema of the array to be stringified, you can just build a simple function around that.

```js
let foo = [{a: 1}, {b: 2}];

function stringify(arr){
  let k1 = Object.keys(arr[0])[0];
  let v1 = arr[0][k1];
  let k2 = Object.keys(arr[1])[0];
  let v2 = arr[1][k2];
  return `${k1}_${v1}_${k2}_${v2}`;
}

console.log(stringify(foo)); // a_1_b_2
```

This isn't Code Golf - the shortest, most clever, most "elegant" solution is not necessarily always the best one to use. Good luck looking at some of the other solutions 6 months from now and trying to quickly and easily decipher what the function is doing at a glance.